# How recognize an array in string? With regex in Java

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to make an regular expression to recognize if a given String is an array or not.

For example,

```
String foo = "a[1]";    // true
String bar = "b[]";     // true
String tar = "test";    // false
String zoo = "b[][]"    // true
```

How can I recognize it?

I try something like this:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[_a-zA-Z][_a-zA-Z0-9]*");
```

But I don't know how represent the "[" and "]" characters.

Thank's in advance.

Comment: By escaping them with a backslash (which has to be doubled in a string literal - `\\​​​`.

Comment: This is vague. Is `b[][]` considered an array in your case? What about `b[]a[]`? You should make it more clear what are the possible inputs.

Comment: Of course, `b[][]` is and array too.

Comment: What is the purpose of this regex? Are you trying to find arrays in Java code? If so you will also need to handle references like `[]a[]` which is same as `[][]a` or `a[][]`.

Comment: I'm writting a little compiler of a programming language with JFLEX and CUP, and I need this regex for make a method. The array declarations is C like, and only need `a[]` or `a[][]` or `a[][][]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[_a-zA-Z]+(?:\\[[_a-zA-Z0-9]*\\])+");
```

This should do it for you.`escape` `[]`.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/sS2dM8/17

Answer (score 0):

try this it match all array type

```
[a-zA-Z_]+(?:\\[\d*\\])+
```

Comment: I think that this regex don't recognize identifiers inside []. Like `a[i]`